# $R$ be a commutative ring , $A$ be an $R$-algebra , $M$ be an $A$-module , $M_m$ is flat over $R_{m\cap R}$ for every $m\in max(A)$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, localization, flatness

Let $R$ be a commutative ring , $A$ be an $R$-algebra , $M$ be an $A$-module . If for every maximal ideal $m$ of $A$ , we have $M_m$ is flat   over $R_{m\cap R}$ ; then how to show that $M$ is flat over $R$ ?

I know that it is enough to show that $M_p$ is flat over $R_p$ for every maximal ideal $p$ of $R$ ; can we show this from my conditions , or is there any other way to proceed ? Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: you can read this basic property in Atiyah's book.

Comment: $M=0$ iff $M_m=0$

Comment: @Sky : I know that ... but the thing is , can we say $M_m=0$ for all maximal ideals $m$ of $R$ from my conditions ?

Comment: Theorem 7.1, Matsumura CRT.